# Проблема с подключением класа

Tags: c#

Значит стандартный код, для старта софта...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace new_class
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1 klas1 = new Class1();
        }
    }
}
```

а здесь пишет ошибку и хз что делать...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace new_class
{
    class Class1
    {
        public static **klas1**()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("123");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Мне надо чтобы софт выводил именно 123 и именно из класса..

Comment: приведите пожалуйста код ошибки

Comment: `public Class1() { Console.WriteLine("123");  Console.ReadKey(); }` - это называется конструктор класса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`public static **klas1**()`

В имени метода не должны содержаться спец. символы. У метода также нужно указывать тип возвращаемого значения, в вашем случае `void`.

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public class ExampleClass
    {
        public static void Write123()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("123");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExampleClass.Write123();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Как указал @Igor в комментариях, можно просто добавить вывод нужной вам информации в конструктор класса. Тогда при создании экземпляра класса конструктор выведет её автоматически.

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    public ExampleClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("123");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new ExampleClass();
    }
}
```